# How to change the content of the 401 response to individual format?

Tags: jax-rs, http-status-code-401, custom-error-pages

I have a JAX-RS application on WildFly 10 which shall be secured by a simple Basic Auth.

It works so far, but if the authentication fails, the server responds with

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
  <body>Unauthorized</body>
</html>
```

which is not my desired response. I would prefer a customized (json) response.

*How to do that?*

What I did so far:

1. I configured a new Wildfly security domain in my server configuration with a simple UserRolesLoginModule (which is sufficient in my case):

   ```
   <security-domain name="MySecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
     <authentication>
       <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
         <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
         <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>                            
         <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
         <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
         <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
         <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="UnauthenticatedAccess"/> 
       </login-module>                                       
     </authentication>
   </security-domain>
   ```
2. I annotated all services in the app:

   ```
        @SecurityDomain("MySecurityDomain")
        @RolesAllowed({ "RoleFromPropertyFile", "AnotherRoleFromPropertyFile" })
   ```
3. I created a jboss-web.xml with the content

   ```
       <jboss-web>
         <security-domain>MySecurityDomain</security-domain>
       </jboss-web>
   ```
4. I have a web.xml where I tried a lot of different things without any success... :-(
   Current content:

   ```
       <security-constraint>
         <display-name>Deny all HTTP methods except GET and POST</display-name>
         <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>NextTest</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>/mypattern/*</url-pattern>
           <http-method-omission>GET</http-method-omission>
           <http-method-omission>POST</http-method-omission>
        </web-resource-collection>    
      </security-constraint>
      <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>MySecurityRealm</realm-name>
      </login-config>
     <security-role>
        <description>Access to all application parts</description>
        <role-name>all</role-name>
    </security-role>    
    <!-- and some more roles -->
   ```
5. I also implemented a `ExceptionMapper<EJBAccessException>` to generate my own response. But this mapper is only reached when I remove all content of `web.xml`.

My guess is that undertow is doing the authorization and handles the response on unauthorized access. If I remove the security configuration in the `web.xml`, the EJBs are accessed, but without evaluating the BasicAuth header. In this case, all requests are denied.

*I possible I would avoid to write a  Servlet and use an ExceptionMapper instead.*

Any ideas what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment with some code and, while it's not pretty, you could try something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class AuthBodyResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        if((responseContext.getStatus() == 401) && 
           (responseContext.getEntity() instanceof String))
            responseContext.setEntity("no services for you!");
    }
}
```

I tested it a bit and it seems to work.  Of course, the challenge is where else is there a 401 with a String response body?  I'd have to test more to see if this covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response create(Entity entity) {
    try {
        Entity created = service().create(entity);
        return Response.created(location(created)).entity(created).build();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        return Response.status(e.getStatus()).entity(e).build();
    }
}
```

Notice the return type, [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html). This allows you to customize the response, including setting headers etc. It also means you have to write some more wiring code.

I'm using a custom `ServiceException` here that already has the status in it and use it to set the response code. Then I pass the exception itself which will be returned as JSON.